# Xdocument Descendants function gives exception

Tags: c#, xml

I loaded an html document in the Xdocument object :

```
XDocument xdoc = Xdocument.load(path);
XElement el = new XElement("name","value");

xdoc.Descendants("body").Single().Add(el);  <=== sequence conatin no element
```

document contains the body element, then why this exception is coming ?

Comment: Could you post your sample XML, I believe you have Namespace as well in your xml

Comment: No it is just a simple Html document `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: Can you post the full exception with the call stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that it can't find the `body` element due to namespacing. If it's in a namespace, you can find it using:

```
XNamespace ns = "whatever the namespace uri is";
xdoc.Descendants(ns + "body").Single().Add(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
xdoc.Root.Descendants("body").Single().Add(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find element without Namespase, just use LocalName in XElement

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("Data.xml");
root.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "body")
```